# How to set the dropdown width of Jquery mulitselect

Tags: jquery, multi-select, jquery-ui-multiselect

I am using below plugin to achieve multiselect functionality
http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

My items width in dropdown more the control, is there any way to set increase the dropdown width based on the length of the items. The actual control width should be normal, when they open that control the width of the dropdown should be more.

if you guys need some more info, please let me know

Comment: you need the 'change' event , and then read the length, and based on that set .css({ 'width' : 'myNewWidthpx' })

Comment: can you give me sample, if we do this way it wont increase the control width right ? I want to increase just the dropdown width. Without finding the lenght can we set the width to a value ?

Comment: I have the same issue, looking for answers

Comment: I have the same issue, any luck ??

Answer (score 0):

Change the css width of the class **ms-container** to your desired width!

`.ms-container {
     width: 550px;
 }`